# How to use grgit describe operation

Tags: git, gradle

My requirement is to get the current tag on which I am working on . I am using it like below :

```
task showTag <<{
def grgit = org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.open(dir: 'C:\\Rep7')
def description = grgit.describe().toString().trim()
}
```

But this when executed says through CLI gives output as build successful,but doesnt display anything. How do I display the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **logger** to log you result
use `logger.lifecycle(your message)` to intermediate state messages
use `logger.debug(your message)` to print debug messages //use --debug to see message
use `logger.info(your message)` to print info messages //use --info to see info messages